# How do I prevent buttons being disabled inside a ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

In the following code, swiping from one card to another seems to disable the button inside the ScrollView. I've identified the problem as being the .mask line in ScrollPart (.clippedShape creates a similar problem and doesn't fit my design goals), unfortunately, though, in the actual project I'm working on, I can't get rid of it for the sake of the visual appearance

```
import SwiftUI

extension AnyTransition {
    public static func swipe(_ edge: Edge) -> AnyTransition {
        .asymmetric(insertion: move(edge: edge), removal: move(edge: edge.flip()))
    }
}

extension Edge {
    public func flip() -> Edge {
        switch self {
        case .bottom:
            return .top
        case .top:
            return .bottom
        case .leading:
            return .trailing
        case .trailing:
            return .leading
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index: Int = 0
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var transition = AnyTransition.identity
    @State var ID = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollPart(index: self.index)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .background(Background())
                .offset(x: self.offset)
                .id(self.ID)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged {value in
                            self.offset = value.translation.width
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        if self.offset > geometry.size.width * 0.4 {
                            self.index += 1
                            self.ID = UUID()
                            
                            self.transition = .swipe(.leading)
                        }
                        if self.offset < -geometry.size.width * 0.4 {
                            self.index -= 1
                            self.ID = UUID()
                            
                            self.transition = .swipe(.trailing)
                        }
                        
                        self.offset = 0
                    }
                )
                .transition(self.transition)
                .animation(.easeOut)
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollPart: View {
    var index : Int
    @State var bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Spacer().frame(height: 300)
            Button (action: {self.bool.toggle()}){
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(
                            style:
                            StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1,
                                        dash: [10, 1])).foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 120)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                Text("Index: \(self.index)")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                .padding()
                }
            }
            Text(bool ? "True" : "False")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
        }
    .mask(Background())
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct Background: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .frame(width: 0.9 * geometry.size.width, height: 0.9 * geometry.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

I've been struggling with this for a while, but I'm still hoping there's some way I can keep the mask, but also fix the problem of the button being disabled inside the ScrollView. The button does get re-enabled if you scroll the ScrollView, but this is still a design flaw that ideally could be fixed. I don't know a lot of UIKit, I've basically just started learning SwiftUI and have only learned the old ways whenever absolutely necessary, so I'd appreciate it if UIKit answers keep in mind that I may struggle understanding it
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Tested with Xcode 12 - buttons work fine.

Comment: So it’s a bug in the current version and I should just try the beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to delete or modify the line .mask(Background()), mask in Apple Docs "The view whose alpha the rendering system applies to the specified view." "Use mask(_:) when you want to apply the alpha (opacity) value of another view to the current view." Apply mask with the same background and inside this background view a Geometry Reader affects to the button inside the Scroll View.

If you comment //.mask(Background) works fine to me and show the white borders fine too. Another solution using mask adding a VStack on ScrollView and apply mask without Geometry Reader. If you apply an opacity to this mask is working fine too(change .mask(Background1()) to .mask(Rectangle().opacity(0.6)))

```
    struct Background1: View {
      var body: some View {
         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
           .foregroundColor(.green)
         }
     }

    struct ScrollPart: View {
      var index : Int
      @State var bool = false

      var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
          VStack {
             Spacer().frame(height: 300)
             Button (action: {self.bool.toggle()}){
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(
                            style:
                            StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, dash: [10,1])).foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 120)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                    Text("Index: \(self.index)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()
                    }
               }
               Text(bool ? "True" : "False")
                 .foregroundColor(.white)
                 .font(.title)
            }
            .mask(Background1()) 
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: This does look like it works! I'm not entirely sure why it works though. Just a quirk of SwiftUI being new I guess? Still though, thanks